# Bigquery JSON String to columns and rows

Tags: json, google-bigquery, extract

I have a BigQuery table that contains a column that contains a JSON string. I am new to using both.

Within the JSON, there are key value pairs - but some are nested arrays and some are not.  And the nesting is at different levels.

Example:

```
{
  "participant_id": "12345",
  "rd_visit_focus_area": [
    "Wt Management",
    " Eating Healthier meals",
    " Eating more fruits and vegetables",
    " decreasing salty foods",
    " decreasing sugary foods",
    " family meals",
    " home cooking "
  ],
  "demog_work_schedule": "",
  "Comments": "",
  "health": {
    "center": "Health Center 1",
    "height": "5 ft 10 in",
    "weight": "226 lbs",
    "conditions": [
      "Obesity",
      " cholesterol",
      " hypoparathyroidism"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried MANY solutions found online  - most don't work - but the best was using the JSON functions below.

These 'sort of' work within Biqquery - but there 2 issues with using these functions:

1. Not all key value pairs are extracted
2. I need this SQL to execute inside Tableau and Tableau does not support using these functions

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_keys(input STRING) RETURNS Array<String>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_values(input STRING) RETURNS Array<String>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
```

Is there a sql solution that does not use functions?

This is my first time posting a question here - so if I'm missing any necessary info to help solve this problem, please let me know!

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create direct functions by removing the temp keyword. Then you would be able to use it as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help sarath.mec.  Using non-temp functions will solve my tableau problem - but I still don't know how to get all the levels of the JSON extracted.  When I run the function I only get the top-level key/value pairs.

Comment: How would I extract health.conditions.obesity?